# Create Jira ticket with markdown

Tags: rest, markdown, jira

I am using this Jira API to create ticket: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-issue-post

I am able to get the ticket created, but the markdown string I put in the `description` field was rendered in a broken way.

So far, the bold and link markdown works, but the table and code block don't work. (I was following this official document: https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables)

It may not related to my issue, but I also found another weird thing: 
If you create issue via button `A`, the table and code block markdown syntax works, but if you create ticket via button `B`, it will not work.

[image]

However for the working one, if you edit the description, you will find this message `This text has unsupported formatting` in the editor:

[image]

It seems to me all the API submitted descriptions are rendered using the button `B` algorithm.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out it was my Ruby String quote added extra escape:

```
2.1.3 :001 > '\n'
"\\n"
2.1.3 :002 > "\n"
"\n"
```